# Could not receive email from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I stopped receiving email from my WordPress site . I have tried with wp-smtp and postman plugins for all i`m able get the test messages from the plugins but not the real messages from contact form . Hence i opened class added two lines of code in the

```
function mailPassthru()
{
     echo mail('manojurfriend@gmail.com', $subject,'<b>hi</b>',$header);
     echo mail('manojurfriend@gmail.com', $subject,$body,$header);
}
```

both returns 1 .
but i am able to receive mail only from first function not from second function means i can get only hi as content not the WordPress content .

Could anybody help on this??

Comment: Where $body is get it's value ?

Comment: $body value come from different places whenever wordpress trries a mail it calls this class file.

Comment: you can see after the body submitting this form http://jennisandwarmann.uk/contact-us/ I printed the $body after submitting

Comment: From where wordpress gets the $body? And how are you accessing the $body within a function? The way you access $body is a local variable to that function. Get the $body and then try.

Comment: body is function parameter  private function mailPassthru($to, $subject, $body, $header, $params)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
function mailPassthru()
{
mail('manojurfriend@gmail.com', $subject,'<b>hi</b>',$header);
}
```

Comment: syntax i have written is what you mentioned but mail with content hi is receiving but mail with actual content in $ body is received

Comment: if you use html content than please use this header--
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: No luck i used your the headers but still only hi is receiving not the actual content mail

Comment: Please provide some details too

Comment: $body=mysql_real_escape_string($body);
use this code before mail function

Comment: no it also dint work

Comment: @altafhussain my site is a wordpress site in class-phpmailer.php i puit the following code echo mail('manojurfriend@gmail.com', $subject,'<b>hi</b>',$header);
echo mail('manojurfriend@gmail.com', $subject,$body,$header); both themail function executed i receive only one mail which content is hi where in case i dint receive the actual content stored in $body